# How to toggle `<div>` items upon click of another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, show-hide

I have `<div>` structure like this

```
<!-- Parent -->     
<div id="parentCategory" >
    <input type="image" src="a.jpg" onClick="showNextCat('nextCategory1', 'block', 'nextCategory2', 'nextCategory3')" />
    <input type="image" src="b.jpg" onClick="showNextCat('nextCategory2', 'block', 'nextCategory1', 'nextCategory3')" />
    <input type="image" src="c.jpg" onClick="showNextCat('nextCategory3', 'block', 'nextCategory1', 'nextCategory2')" />
    ...
</div>

<!-- 1st Child -->      
<div id="nextCategory1" style="display: none;">
    <input type="image" src="1a.jpg" />
    <input type="image" src="1b.jpg" />
</div>


<!-- 2nd Child -->      
<div id="nextCategory2"  style="display: none;">
    <input type="image" src="2a.jpg" />
    <input type="image" src="2b.jpg" />
</div>  


<!-- 3rd Child -->      
<div id="nextCategory3"  style="display: none;">
    <input type="image" src="3a.jpg" />
    <input type="image" src="3b.jpg" />
</div>
```

My JS

```
function showNextCat(id, visibility, h1, h2) {
    var item = document.getElementById(id);
    document.getElementById(h1).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(h2).style.display = "none";

    if (item.style.display !== "none") {
        item.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        item.style.display = visibility;    
    }   
}
```

I don't want to hardcode the `showNextCat()` method to hide `non-selected` `<div>`

Please Improvise the JS method.

Comment: you can use jQuery provided `toggleClass( className )`

Comment: You also shouldn't want to use inline JS, you know... And if you are going to use jQuery, it's time to rewrite your JS code nearly completely.

Comment: Ok thanks @Rakesh and @Regent.. I'll use jQuery `toggleClass`... Any link or example ?

Comment: @ShadabMehdi something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/183gpdy3/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using jQuery you can make this easy. first thing to do, remove all the `onClick` events from your buttons. then, you have to define a css class for the selected divs :

```
.selected  {
   display : block;
}
```

then on the buttons, specify the id of the category concerned, for example

```
<input type="image" src="a.jpg" select-category="nextCategory1" />
```

all you need to do now, is to define the click event for all the buttons

```
$("[select-category]").click(function () {
    $("#" + $(this).attr("select-category")).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

**Note :** this is not the only solutions.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 possible option either if you are using jquery
then it will be easier.

Let's see first jQuery's solution

1. Apply `class="category"` to all the element which you want to manipulate dynamically.
2. put value in html want to show like `data-show="nextCategory1"`
3. apply css

   ```
   .category{
       display:none;
   }
   ```
4. Put this JS function

   ```
   $('#parentCategory input').on('click',function(e){
       $('.category').hide();
       $('#'+$(this).data('show')).show();
   });
   ```

[View Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nil4you/v4n6j4ec/1/)

Now Let's see Javascript solution which is also bit of simillar

```
function showNextCat(id) {
var item = document.getElementById(id);
var elem = document.querySelectorAll(".category")
var i;
for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    elem[i].style.display='none';
}
    item.style.display='block';
}
```

[View Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/nil4you/5cLwx1ur/2/)